# Prove that $S^n \not \simeq S^1 $ for any $n >1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

This question is from my lecture in topology class and I am not able to make any significant progress on it.

Question: Prove that $S^n$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^1 $ for any $n >1$.

I am very  sorry to say but I don't have any thing to show as attempt here as I am very new to algberaic topology. So, I request you to please outline a proof.

Comment: Do you know the first homotopy groups?

Comment: @Randall Yes , I have studied about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two spaces are homotopy equivalent, they have isomorphic homotopy groups. For the question, the 1st homotopy group, namely the fundamental group, is trivial for $S^n\ (n>1)$ but is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ for $S^1$. Hence, they are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Another degree to see will be $\pi_n$. In fact, $\pi_n(S^n)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ via associating the degree. But for $n>1$, $\pi_n(S^1)=0$ because its universal covering, $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible. This gives another reasoning.